# Existence of the measure $\mu_{\psi}$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $A$ be a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$. Let $\rho(A)$ the resolvent set of $A$ and, for each $\lambda \in \rho(A)$, let $R_{A}(\lambda) := (\lambda I -A)^{-1}$ its associated resolvent. This is a well-defined linear operator on $\mathscr{H}$ so we can consider the inner product $f_{\psi}(\lambda) := \langle \psi, R_{A}(\lambda)\psi\rangle$, where $\psi \in \mathscr{H}$ is fixed.

In my lecture notes, my professor says that because (a) $f_{\psi}(\bar{z}) = \overline{f_{\psi}(z)}$, (b) $|f_{\psi}(\lambda)| \le ||\psi||^{2}/\operatorname{Im(z)}$ and (c) $\operatorname{Im}(f_{\psi}(z)) = \operatorname{Im(z)}||R_{A}(\lambda)\psi||^{2}$, then there exists a measure $\mu_{\psi}$ on $\mathbb{B}(\mathbb{R})$ on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra such that:
$$f_{\psi}(\lambda) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{z-\lambda}d\mu_{\psi}(z)$$

**Question:** What is being used here so we can garantee the existence of such measure $\mu_{\psi}$? I did not follow the reasoning. Is it some sort of Riesz Representation Theorem (for positive functionals)?